# What does over-the-counter mean literally?

Tags: etymology

I've found references that this term is originally used for the purchase of stocks that not listed on the stock exchange.

From etymology.com:

> Adjective phrase over-the-counter is attested from 1875, originally of stocks and shares.

It seems like it could mean two things:

- Stock is sold retail rather than through an exchange. The exchange takes place simply by handing the stock "over the counter" rather than through a third party exchange.
- Stock is sold "on the other side of the counter" rather than "behind" the counter which implies unlisted.

I would be appreciative if someone with an OED subscription wouldn't mind taking a look and seeing if maybe this was derived from another term or if some of the earlier documented references of its use could give some hints.

Comment: Good question. I'll be waiting for an answer with you.

Comment: This question is about the provenance of the term, which is in finances. For perspective (in case people are confused like I was) there is a second medical meaning: the first thing that comes to mind is 'I bought some over-the-counter pain relievers for my back' meaning I bought some medicine available in a drug store without needing a prescription (necessitating a doctor to prescribe it and a pharmacist to prepare it). For example, a bottle of aspirin is usually sold over-the-counter.

Comment: @Mitch - I think the medical/finance idiomatic usage is explained in the answer, but OP seems to be asking for the original meaning of OTC, before it was used idiomatically.

Comment: @Josh61 You're all well ahead of me. I just wanted to put a sign post here for people like me who might be confused expecting a question about going to the drugstore when really it's about where that came from. I've always wondered what OTC stocks, and why they would be described with the same words as pharmaceuticals. Now I know it's the other way round.

Answer (score 5):

[Over-the -counter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=over%20the%20counter&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cover%20the%20counter%3B%2Cc0) is quite an old expression whose meaning is just literal, and refer to an informal sale, generally in a shop,  without any specific rule or prescription.  (Ngram)

> - [Mr. PURVER](https://books.google.it/books?id=a0A1AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PA47&dq=%22over%20the%20counter%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=B7SHVf_NH4qsU9qlgbgN&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22over%20the%20counter%22&f=false):' ***In England, nearly all bread was sold over the counter*** ; here, it was nearly all sold by delivery. In England, the bread was weighed over the counter. Mr. O'CONNOR said he was very glad to have received the deputation and to ...(Votes & Proceedings, Volume 2 -1803
>     Di New South Wales. Parliament. Legislative Council)
> - [B.S. Keeps](http://B.%20S.%20keeps%20in%20a%20small%20town%20a%20wine%20and%20spirit%20vaults,%20selling%20over%20the%20counter,%20and%20(%20on%20market%20days%20only)%20providing%20also%20rooms%20for%20customers%20to%20sit%20down%20in.%20B.%20S.%20does%20not%20reside%20at%20the%20premises,%20but%20they%20belong%20to%20and%20are%20occupied%20by%20a%20relative%20,%20...) ***in a small town a wine and spirit vaults, selling over the counter***, and ( on market days only) providing also rooms for customers to sit down in. B. S. does not reside at the premises, but they belong to and are occupied by a relative , ...(Justice of the Peace and Local Government Review, Volume 12-1844)

- The idea is that  of a shop, where you generally have a counter with on one side the shop-assistant and a client on the other side. ***The product is sold and handed over the counter to the client*** .  Nowadays you help yourself at the counter and go to the cashier directly. –

Idiomatically it is commonly used in  ([pharmacy](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/over-the-counter)) and finance:

> - Legal for sale or distribution without the requirement of a prescription (of medicine and other treatments); abbreviated as OTC. (Wiktionary)

- *[Over-the-counter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_(finance))* in finance,  simply refers to an exchange of shares or bonds which are not listed in official markets, or , even though they are listed, volumes are too thin to allow proper transactions, so OTC transaction are carried out between a buyer and a seller,  generally through a brokerage house, but without going thorough the official markets. (Wikipedia)

Comment: You refer to what the over-the-counter idiom means, but i what I've asked (or meant to ask) it what the literal words "over the counter" mean in this context, without an idiom. Does it mean on the other side of the counter? Or that we're selling it by passing the item on top of the counter?

Comment: Or rather, why is it called over-the-counter. Where did such an expression come from originally?

Comment: The reference is to a shop, where you generally have a counter and on the one side the shop-assistant while on the other side the client. The product is sold and handed over the counter to the client. That is the image. The highlighted sentence above *bread is sold over the counter* refers to that kind of sale. Nowadays you help yourself at the counter and go to the cashier directly.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Do you have any more examples?

Comment: Arguably, 'over the counter' meaning '[to be found] on the opposite side of the counter' could be described as a 'literal' usage. Prepositional usage is far from simple, and the degree of metaphor used in individual usages complex and debated. But a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is my understanding that in speaking specifically to the OTC Market for stock transactions, orignally the securities were traded over-the-counter (near the NYSE) prior to becoming a formalized exchange in 1904.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The preceding automatically posted comment is misleading. The problem with the answer is not that it needs 'supporting information', but that it does not address the question. The current meaning of the phrase in the finances-related contexts is well known; the OP and others who contributed to this page already know it. The question is about the relationship of that meaning to the literal meanings of the words that constitute it.